# PHP Structuring an if statement inside an if else statement

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, if-statement

I have created an if statement inside the "else" of an if/else statement.It works.However the code below the function does not run.When i remove the function the code below the function runs.Could you please help me out.

This code causes the problem:

```
<?php $googleplay= get_option('director_googleplay');?>
<?php if($googleplay): ?>
    <a href="<?php print $googleplay; ?>">
       <img src="<?=IMAGES?>/googleplay.png" class=" img-responsive  top-buffer-5"  alt="Image"/>
    </>
<?php endif;;?>
```

The php:

```
<?php  $category_id = get_cat_ID('Category Name'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if ( in_category("1") ) { ?>
       <div class="section"></div>

    <?php } elseif ( in_category("2") ) { ?>
       <div class="section"></div>

  <?php } else { ?>
      <div class="section">
          <?php $googleplay= get_option('director_googleplay');?>
          <?php if($googleplay): ?>
              <a href="<?php print $googleplay; ?>"><img src="<?=IMAGES?>/googleplay.png" class=" img-responsive  top-buffer-5"  alt="Image"/></>
          <?php endif;;?> 
       </div>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endwhile;else: ?>
    <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="section">
    <?php $facebook= get_option('director_facebook');
    <?php if($facebook): ?>
    <a href="<?php print $facebook; ?>"><img src="<?=IMAGES?>/Facebook.png" class=" img-responsive pull-left"alt="Image"/></>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Good grieve, people still write code using that embedded style of php?

Comment: First, *what is the error message you are getting*? Second, the short and the long versions are not the same. Third, "the php" has an unidentified `endwhile` in there. Among other errors.

Comment: @arkascha: There's nothing wrong with that style. The problem here is that the code is a mess because there's too much embedded logic and the granularity is not quite right.

Comment: arkascha: Wordpress forces you. This is the only way for templates.

Comment: @Jon: I never said something is wrong with the style. It is just that such code is a mess because there's too much embedded logic. ;-)

Comment: @nekaab: that is not true. I wrote some wordpress modifications. I never used such style.

Comment: The correct answer to this question is probably: "use a templating engine"

Comment: @arkascha Ok, can you point me somewhere where it's explained how to write WP-Templates without snippets?

Comment: Turn on debugging and find out what the errors are. define('WP_DEBUG', true);

Comment: Also, is IMAGES defined? Constants need to be echo'ed for output.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you forgot to close the `<a>`-Tag: `</a>`, not `</>`. However, the Code should still "run", just display garbage.

Additionally, php snippets can also be started and ended by the `<?`-Tag, you have one of those in your code:

`<img src="/googleplay.png" class=" img-responsive  top-buffer-5"  alt="Image"/>`

should work. Remove `<?=IMAGES?>` which probably causes the problem. What are you trying to do with `<?=IMAGES?>`?

Comment: Hi nekaab. I am using the <?=IMAGES?> to retrieve code from the functions where <?=IMAGES?> is acting to get the location of the images.

Comment: Ok i got it working by adding an extra else statement to it. Though it doesn't make sense.Must be some wordpress error